# ¿ Como hago un efecto de temblor a un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animación

EDITO LA PREGUNTA:

A petición de varios compañeros, edito la pregunta.
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que la flecha del margen izquierdo no cambie de posición al pulsarla ( Se sube hacia arriba cuando se pulsa ), y a su vez, haga un temblor automatico y  cada cierto tiempo, como el que hace el botón del centro al pasarle al pasarle el ratón por encima, pero la flecha le haga automáticamente y cada cierto tiempo.
Espero haberme explicado.
Gracias y perdón por las malas explicaciones.

Estoy tratando que el botón de ocultar un menú, el cual me ayudaron a crear (@Camilo Vasquez, @Luis Daniel Rovira Contreras, @Ricardo Sánchez )la fecha que se muestra en el borde izquierdo de la pantalla en ejemplo, haga un efecto temblor de vez en cuando, para llamar su atención. Y a su vez no se desplace hacia arriba al pulsarla.  Hasta ahora solo he conseguido con la documentación de w3c y viendo tutoriales, lo que muestra el botón central.
Este lo hace al pasar el mouse por encima, pero no consigo que la flecha lo haga autonómicamente y de vez en cuando.
He visto varios ejemplos, como los creados por @Edgar Gutierrez, pero soy incapaz de implantarlo en mi botón.
Espero con el ejemplo explicarme.
Gracias.
EDITO:

```js
        function ocultar(){
            $(".lateral").hide();
            $("#mostrar").show();
        }
        function mostrar(){
            $(".lateral").show();
            $("#mostrar").hide();
        }

        /*funcion de camilo Vasquez
        function ocultar(){
            $("#ocultar").css('opacity', 0);
            $(".lateral").not("#ocultar").parent().animate({
                left: -42,
                opacity: 0
            }, 300);
            $("#mostrar").show();
        }
        
        function mostrar(){
            $("#ocultar").css('opacity', 1);
            $(".lateral").parent().animate({
                left: -0,
                opacity: 1
            }, 300);
            $("#mostrar").hide();
        }*/
```

```css
/* Estilos de las pestañas*/
/* CREADO CON AYUDA DE @Flowen y @Camilo Vasquez */

/* Primer Cambios de Camilo Vasquez*/
body{
 background: #ccc;
}


#mostrar{
    display:none;
    }

*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:200px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.social ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*.social ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms; 
    -0-transition:all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms
}*/

.social ul li a {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease; 
}

.social ul li  .icon-facebook {background: #3b5998 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-twitter {background:#00abf0 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-youtube {background:#F8030E   ;}
.social ul li  .icon-google {background: #d95232;}
.social ul li  .icon-envelop {background: #666666  ;}
.social ul li  .icon-blogger2 {background:#F88103 ;}

/* Cambios de Camilo Vasquez
.social ul li  .icon-chevron-left{background: #88F34F;}
.social ul li  .icon-chevron-right{background: #88F34F;}
.social ul li a:hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}*/

.social ul li .boton_flecha{
 background: transparent;
 color:black;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.social ul li a:not(.boton_flecha):hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}

.social ul li a#mostrar{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}


/*ESTILOS DE BOTON CENTRAL*/


  @-webkit-keyframes animar {
   0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
  }

  .temblor {
   margin-top: 300px;
   margin-left: 300px;
   background: gray;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   font-family: Arial;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
  }

  .temblor:hover {
   -webkit-animation: animar .6s 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Social</title>

 <!--Este es el font de la flecha de ocultar barra de redes que me proporciono Camilo Vazquez -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!--/fin de font de Camilo Vasquez-->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="redes.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>

<body>

 <div class="social">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="lateral boton_flecha" id="ocultar" onclick="ocultar()">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="boton_flecha" onclick="mostrar()" id="mostrar">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <!--BOTON QUE TIEMBLA AL PASAR EL MOOUSE-->

 <div class='temblor'>
  <span>Efecto temblor</span>
 </div>
 <script src="redes.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Veo que el botón y hace el temblor on Hover. Quieres que *"la flecha lo haga autonómicamente y de vez en cuando. "*...no entiendo eso . Qué flecha?

Comment: Redacte mejor su pregunta para que lo puedan ayudar mejor.

Comment: Tienes que explicarte mejor amigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: Edite la pregunta, espero esta mas claro lo que intento hacer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero es que al dar `click` en el botón estás "removiendo" el primer botón, es por eso que se te sube y no queda en el lugar que debe de ser, la solución no es removerlo simplemente es esconderlo...he añadido la animación a tu botón con un ligero cambio en la propiedad `translate` espero sea de tu agrado.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $(".boton_flecha").addClass('animacion');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".boton_flecha").removeClass('animacion');
    }, 1000)
}, 5000)

function ocultar(){
    $(".lateral").css('opacity', 0);
    $("#mostrar").show();
}

function mostrar(){
    $(".lateral").css('opacity', 1);
    $("#mostrar").hide();
}
```

```css
/* Estilos de las pestañas*/
/* CREADO CON AYUDA DE @Flowen y @Camilo Vasquez */

/* Primer Cambios de Camilo Vasquez*/
body{
    background: #ccc;
}


#mostrar{
    display:none;
    }

*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:100px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.social ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*.social ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms; 
    -0-transition:all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms
}*/

.social ul li a:not(.boton_flecha){
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease; 
}

.social ul li  .icon-facebook {background: #3b5998 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-twitter {background:#00abf0 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-youtube {background:#F8030E   ;}
.social ul li  .icon-google {background: #d95232;}
.social ul li  .icon-envelop {background: #666666  ;}
.social ul li  .icon-blogger2 {background:#F88103 ;}

/* Cambios de Camilo Vasquez
.social ul li  .icon-chevron-left{background: #88F34F;}
.social ul li  .icon-chevron-right{background: #88F34F;}
.social ul li a:hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}*/

.social ul li .boton_flecha{
    background: transparent;
    color:black;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.social ul li a:not(.boton_flecha):hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}

.animacion{
    -webkit-animation: animar .6s linear;
}

.social ul li a#mostrar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/*ESTILOS DE BOTON CENTRAL*/
@-webkit-keyframes animar {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

.temblor {
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    background: gray;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.temblor:hover {
    -webkit-animation: animar .6s 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="lateral boton_flecha" id="ocultar" onclick="ocultar()">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="boton_flecha" onclick="mostrar()" id="mostrar">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa un intervalo y la funcion shake.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){ $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" ); }, 3000);
});
```

```css
  #toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>shake demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="toggle"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

### Definición y uso

El método `setInterval()` llama a una función o evalúa una expresión a intervalos específicos (en milisegundos).

El método `setInterval()` continuará llamando a la función hasta que se invoque clearInterval () o se cierre la ventana.

El valor ID devuelto por `setInterval()` se usa como el parámetro para el método `clearInterval()`.

Consejo: 1000 ms = 1 segundo.

Consejo: Para ejecutar una función solo una vez, luego de un número específico de milisegundos, use el método setTimeout ().

Efecto Shake
Descripción: agita el elemento varias veces, vertical u horizontalmente.

---

### Shake

**Dirección** (predeterminado: "izquierda")

Tipo: *String*

Un valor de "izquierda" o "derecha" sacudirá el elemento horizontalmente, y un valor de "arriba" o "abajo" sacudirá el elemento verticalmente. El valor especifica en qué dirección debe moverse el elemento a lo largo del eje para el primer paso del efecto.

**Distancia** (por defecto: 20)

Tipo: *Number*

Distancia para sacudir.

**Veces** (por defecto: 3)

Tipo: *Integer*

Tiempos para sacudir

Comment: Ok, voy a tratar de aplicarlo a mi flecha

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres de que cada cierto tiempo se ejecute lo manejas con un `setInterval()` especificando que función quieres que se ejecute y cada cuanto tiempo en mili segundos. dejo la función que tienes ya que no se si la tienes porque la quieres o quieres aplicarle el temblor que en ese caso ya tienes la función que te proporciono camilo.

```js
function ocultar(){
            $(".lateral").hide();
            $("#mostrar").show();
        };
        function mostrar(){
            $(".lateral").show();
            $("#mostrar").hide();
        };

        /*funcion de camilo Vasquez
        function ocultar(){
            $("#ocultar").css('opacity', 0);
            $(".lateral").not("#ocultar").parent().animate({
                left: -42,
                opacity: 0
            }, 300);
            $("#mostrar").show();
        }
        
        function mostrar(){
            $("#ocultar").css('opacity', 1);
            $(".lateral").parent().animate({
                left: -0,
                opacity: 1
            }, 300);
            $("#mostrar").hide();
        }*/
        
        setInterval('ocultar()', 5000);
        setInterval('mostrar()', 5500);
```

```css
/* Estilos de las pestañas*/
/* CREADO CON AYUDA DE @Flowen y @Camilo Vasquez */

/* Primer Cambios de Camilo Vasquez*/
body{
 background: #ccc;
}


#mostrar{
    display:none;
    }

*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:200px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.social ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*.social ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms; 
    -0-transition:all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms
}*/

.social ul li a {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease; 
}

.social ul li  .icon-facebook {background: #3b5998 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-twitter {background:#00abf0 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-youtube {background:#F8030E   ;}
.social ul li  .icon-google {background: #d95232;}
.social ul li  .icon-envelop {background: #666666  ;}
.social ul li  .icon-blogger2 {background:#F88103 ;}

/* Cambios de Camilo Vasquez
.social ul li  .icon-chevron-left{background: #88F34F;}
.social ul li  .icon-chevron-right{background: #88F34F;}
.social ul li a:hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}*/

.social ul li .boton_flecha{
 background: transparent;
 color:black;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.social ul li a:not(.boton_flecha):hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}

.social ul li a#mostrar{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}


/*ESTILOS DE BOTON CENTRAL*/


  @-webkit-keyframes animar {
   0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   10% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
   90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, 0px);
   }
   100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
  }

  .temblor {
   margin-top: 300px;
   margin-left: 300px;
   background: gray;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   font-family: Arial;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
  }

  .temblor:hover {
   -webkit-animation: animar .6s 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Social</title>

 <!--Este es el font de la flecha de ocultar barra de redes que me proporciono Camilo Vazquez -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!--/fin de font de Camilo Vasquez-->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="redes.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>

<body>

 <div class="social">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="lateral boton_flecha" id="ocultar" onclick="ocultar()">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="boton_flecha" onclick="mostrar()" id="mostrar">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <!--BOTON QUE TIEMBLA AL PASAR EL MOOUSE-->

 <div class='temblor'>
  <span>Efecto temblor</span>
 </div>
 <script src="redes.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo que intento es que la flecha no se mueva al pulsarla y haga el temblor que hace la figura central al pasar el raton, pero automaticamente y de vez encuando sin pasar el raton. Voy a editar la pregunta, pue me dicen que no esta bien formulada. Gracias